# Why mutate applied only to first row and repeats its result to the rest

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame which consists of several columns. One of them is `date_created` column in the unified format. I want to split it into `year`, `month`, `day` and add these columns to the same data frame.

```
input:
id      date_created
1       02-20-2014
2       01-15-2015

result:
id      date_created     year    month    day
1       02-20-2014       2014    2        20
2       01-15-2015       2015    1        15
```

I have a sample code which works incorrect

```
displays <- displays %>%
        mutate(month = as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date, '-')))[1], 
               day   = as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date, '-')))[2],
               year  = as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date, '-')))[3]
              )
```

it produces the following:

```
id      date_created     year    month    day
1       02-20-2014       2014    2        20
2       01-15-2015       2014    2        20
```

I guess that the function is not called for each row, but cannot understand why. Explain, please, how it works and provide the sample code to achieve desired result. Thanks

Comment: In the `mutate`, you are just calling the 1st, 2nd and 3rd element from the entire date column that got split up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `separate` or `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(d1, date_created, c('month', 'day', 'year'), remove=FALSE)
```

Or

```
extract(d1, date_created, c('month', 'day', 'year'),
              '([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)', remove=FALSE)
```

Or `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(d1, 'date_created', sep="-", drop=FALSE)
```

Or using `tstrsplit` from the devel version of `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5
setDT(d1)[, c('month', 'day', 'year') := tstrsplit(date_created, '-')]
```

Regarding the problem in your code, it is just selecting 1st, 2nd and 3rd element from the entire 'date_created' column.  Just use `rowwise`

```
  library(dplyr)
  d1 %>% 
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(month= as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date_created, '-')))[1], 
            day= as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date_created, '-')))[2],
            year=as.integer(unlist(strsplit(date_created, '-')))[3])
```

Or another option would be to convert to date class and then extract 'day', 'month' and 'year'

```
  library(lubridate)
  d1 %>% 
     mutate(date=mdy(date_created), year=year(date),
            month=month(date), day=day(date)) %>% 
     select(-date)
```

Comment: works, thanks, just needed to add separator `-`. Can you explain why `mutate` didn't work?

Comment: @AskhatOmarov I didn't had to add the `sep='-'` for `separate`.  May be it is the version difference.  I used `tidyr_0.2.0`

Comment: @AskhatOmarov Updated with post by correcting your code